# Create a base component to be reused when creating new components

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm putting together an application in which there are many modals. As I do not want to repeat the code of the modal, I want to assemble a base component that has the minimum structure and then with that structure to be able to assemble the different modals and to carry what I need inside (form, text, images)

An example of what I am looking to do

```
<app-modal-base>
  <app-form></app-form>
<app-modal-base>
```

I hope you understand what I'm looking for. In case you can not, someone found an alternative solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your base modal template, include the `<ng-content></ng-content>` tag. When you display your modal, you can use it as follows:

```
<Modal>
  <div id="mydiv">
    <p> Simple paragraph </p>
    <form>...</form>
  </div>
</Modal>
```

The modal will include what you have included between the `<Modal></Modal>` tags at the place where the `<ng-content></ng-content>` tags are in the template for the base modal component. It would look like:

```
template: `
  <div id="closeButton"></div>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
`
```

This information is gathered from [this source](https://alligator.io/angular/content-projection-angular/), and I can't seem to find official docs about this. You might have to try it out.